# Swift UIKit / presenting UIAlert blocks pushing VC

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uialertcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I got simple `UIViewController` + `UIAlert` extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func alert(title: String = "", message: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Localized.ok(), style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Within the ViewController I got a method:

```
    func findUser() {
        userService.findUser { (userinfo, error) in
            if error != nil {
                if let errText = error?.localizedDescription {
                    self.alert(message: errText)
                }
                self.doAuth()
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

this **`doAuth()`** method should redirect to `loginViewController` using:
`navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: false)`

The problem is, that **in this scenario, this push doesn't work (nothing appears)** (I click `OK` button on the alert, alert dissapears but `loginViewController` is not pushed)

I refactored extension a little bit:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func alert(title: String = "", message: String, action completion: (() -> Void)? = nil){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Localized.ok(), style: .default, handler: { _ in
                completion?()
        }))

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

so `findUser()` method is calling `doAuth()` in differently:

```
    func findUser() {
        userService.findUser { (userinfo, error) in
            if error != nil {
                if let errText = error?.localizedDescription {
                    self.alert(message: errText){ [weak self] in
                        self?.doAuth()
                    }
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

and it works!
Problem is I have no idea why. And what could have happened in the first scenario?
I feel it should be some simple explanation, but I can't figure it out.

#### Edit

The explanation is simple and was printed in the console:

```
pushViewController:animated: called on <UINavigationController 0x7f86050b4400> 
while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack 
will not be updated.
```

So `doAuth()` (with pushing VC method) was called while alert was visible/presented, so alert took the focus and VC couldn't be pushed.

cc: @Paulw11 @ cookednick

Comment: In the first code block you are trying to show the alert and then immediately navigate to the login screen. You can't do both at the same time. Also, I am a little suspicious that you are pushing to the login screen. You may be adding an ever-deeper stack of login screens if you get "not found" users. You may want to navigate back to an existing login screen rather than pushing a new one.

Comment: What @Paulw11 said. You can’t present two view controllers at the same time from the same initial VC. Your solution looks good.

Comment: @cookednick you're right. I found in the console: `pushViewController:animated: called on <UINavigationController 0x7f86050b4400> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack  will not be updated.`